# Segmentation Fault 11 in C Inserting node in sorted list

Tags: c, list, segmentation-fault

The error I am getting is Segmentation Fault 11.
The idea is to add nodes into a sorted list in C
What I am having problems is after inserting the first node (which means the list is not empty anymore) that is when I get the error:

```
inserted John
|23,John|
Segmentation fault: 11
```

What doesn't work is when I try to insert a new node node when the list isn't empty.

This is my code:

```
typedef struct StudentListNodeStruct{

int id;
char name[32] ;
struct StudentListNodeStruct *next;
} StudentListNode;

struct StudentListNode *head = NULL;

int insertStudent(StudentListNode **list, int id, char *name){

  StudentListNode *newStudent = (StudentListNode*) malloc (sizeof(StudentListNode));
  strcpy((*newStudent).name, *&name);
  newStudent -> next = NULL;
  StudentListNode *current = head;
  StudentListNode *previous;

  if(findStudent(list,id,name)==0){
    return(1);
  }

  if(head == NULL){
   newStudent -> next == newStudent;
   head = newStudent;
   return(0);
  }

//This while statement is what isn't working

  while(current -> next != NULL && newStudent -> id < id){

     previous = current;
     current = current -> next;

  }
    previous -> next = newStudent;
    newStudent -> next = current;
  }

int findStudent(StudentListNode *list, int id, char *name){
StudentListNode *current = head;
while(current != NULL){
    if(current -> id == id){
        return (0);
    }
    current = current -> next;
}
return (1);
int printList(StudentListNode *list){

StudentListNode *temp = head;
if(temp == NULL){
    printf("(empty list)\n");
}
//start from the beginning
while(temp != NULL) {
  printf("|%d,%s|\n",temp->id,temp->name);
  temp = temp->next;


}
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Please put what you want in the question.

Comment: Try changing `strcpy((*newStudent).name, *&name);` to `newStudent->name = strdup(name);`.  Even though you haven't given us the definition of `StudentListNode`, the field `name` is most likely defined as `char *`, and you haven't allocated any space to hold the name.  The function `strdup` will allocate space for you.

Comment: @bruceg Note that that's assuming POSIX is available. Otherwise a combination of `malloc` and `strcpy` will be needed.

Comment: It leaks. (and: `return` is not a function.

Comment: @wildplasser `return (0);` is a correct way to use the return statement in a function.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR:

- Read 1.
- Read 2.
- Read Solution
- C is frustrating, but it's pretty fun.

A few things:

1. You don't need to cast the return value of malloc, since it
   returns a void pointer.
2. (*newStudent).name is equivalent to newStudent->name. (Ie,
   dereferencing your newStudent pointer and obtaining the name member
   of the StudentListNode struct).

**Your segfault problem (I think):** 
"*&name" is essentially asking to deference the address of the variable name. Remember, &varname will give you the address of variable varname, while pointers to addresses, when dereferenced will "follow" the address in memory "listed" under the variable name.

**Solution:** 
strcpy takes in two arguments (two pointers to strings) 
so you can just send strcpy(newStudent->name, name)

**BUT** before this, you need to malloc for the string name INSIDE the struct newStudent.

Ie, newStudent.name = malloc(sizeof(char)*sizeof(name)), or since sizeof(char) = 1, 
newStudent.name = malloc(sizeof(name)).

**Note:** if you used malloc(strlen(name)), you'd need to account for the null terminator, ie, malloc(strlen(name) + 1). But sizeof will count this for you.

Comment: Only the stuff after the **BUT** actually matters. The rest is just a matter of (very preferable) style.